# Facebook SDK on cocoapods

Tags: cocoapods, xcode4, facebook-ios-sdk

It would be a great idea to get the iOS SDK working with cocoapods, a package manager for iOS apps.

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods

It includes some popular libraries like ASI, Nimbus, etc.

It's a very slick way to ensure that external library management with xcode 4 runs very smoothly.

Comment: It is now officially supported: https://cocoapods.org/?q=FBSDKCoreKit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here you go](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Facebook-iOS-SDK/0.0.1/Facebook-iOS-SDK.podspec) :)

Since they have no tagged releases yet, I currently chose a low version number (0.0.1).

Btw, the repo is nowadays located at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods.

Comment: Dead link. The spec is [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/4a2a7d017cddfdec782da5bbdd2abee353549280/Specs/Facebook-iOS-SDK), and the [Facebook SDK repo](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk).

Comment: @MikeD Official specs were renamed and are now at https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/master/Specs/9/b/5/FBSDKCoreKit